# Display characters with a delay between each in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to make my text appear like its being typed..
like I want to print `you ok` then it must print like
**`y (delay) o (delay) u (delay) (delay) o (delay) k`**... 
my this code works perfect but it always print in the new line

```
        String text = "you ok...:)";
        for(int i=1; i<=text.length();i++){

        System.out.print(text.substring(0, i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you using eclipse to test it?

Comment: You realise you're actually printing "y", then "yo", then "you" etc - so you'll have printed "y" 10 times by the end...

Comment: yeah....bt i want to print it in the same line with each character displayed one time only...

Answer (score 4):

First problem is starting i from 1, it should start from 0. so `charAt(0)` is your first character.

secondly, you should only print the character by using `text.charAt(i)` not the whole substring.

hope this help:

```
   String text = "you ok...:)";
    for(int i=0; i<text.length();i++){

    System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: no it isn't....it just print the whole line at once....but i want it just its being typed on the screen...

Comment: @UmerSajjad hmm not quite sure what you mean, don't you wan't to print the whole String? if you want it to be more human like just increase the sleep to 500

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example which you wants ....

```
public class Stackoverflow {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   String text = "you ok...:)";
   char[] charArr = text.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<=charArr.length-1;i++)
    {

        System.out.print(charArr[i]);
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Using `charAt` as shown in @nafas' answer is a lot more efficient than using `toCharArray`. Also `i<=charArr.length-1` is the same as `i < charArr.length`.